# Vertical Carousel view Android using Viewpager

Tags: android

I was about to create a similar type of Icarousel project in IOS.
     After customization of UI, IOS Carousel looks like this.

[image]

In android I am using Viewpager to get similar type of Card which is one behind the another like this IOS UI. But I couldn't able to achieve the same think like one behind the another using Viewpager Transformation.

[image]

Each card in the carousel is a fragment, and I am scaling it dynamically when it is scrolled up or down. I have read some documentation like viewpager won't allow one fragment to be behind another fragment using transformation. The above android image is looking like the top and bottom card is behind the focussed card, but it is actually scaled not behind. so how to achieve this using ViewPager component not with GalleryView(deprecated) or other View. 
***Code for my Repo*** [Vertical Carousel](https://github.com/Anand-Krish/Vertical-CarouselViewPager)

Comment: Have you tried https://code.google.com/archive/p/carousel-layout-android/  ?

Comment: yeah... have tried. but I want to achieve that using Viewpager only.

Comment: You can achieve using view pager also and I have tried in horizontal and you can do using your custom layout also inside this library. :-)

Comment: can you show any sample code for that. I want one card to be behind the another one like the IOS image I have posted. can you please refer any site code

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/carousel-layout-android/) library.

You can export it to GitHub or download it directly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download sample application code from [here.](https://github.com/applm/CarouselWidget)

I am not sure how to make carousal to vertical because I used this library for horizontal scrooll view only.

1) import this project in android studio.

2) refer [this link](https://github.com/applm/CarouselWidget/issues/1) to make vertical scrolling might be this is helpfully for you.

This is a same library like https://code.google.com/archive/p/carousel-layout-android/

Answer (score -1):

This Android library might also work, however, there are no cards on top of the center card: https://github.com/intuit/truffle-shuffle

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens it is a library that handles all the UI and animation for you, so you only have to add the xml of what's inside of the card and then the data (content) for the cards through an adapter mechanism. If you need any help using it, let me know!